# Window resize function not working for header navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a header navigation which has logo on the left and profile icon on the right in the middle there are some navigation links.

There is a left slide menu made which triggers in when window width is less than 700px. I have triggered slide left menu on window resize event as well. The main navigation has to shift to the responsive menu container on resizing the window width. However it is not working on window resize function.

Here is the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/mustafa2808/pen/BxMVKN) i tried

```js
$("#sidebarCollapse").on('click', function () {
  $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
});  
$(".main-nav li a").on('click', function(){
  $(".main-nav li a").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});  
 

// Menu Add Class Left
$(".hamburger-menu").click(function(){
  $(".mob-menu").toggleClass("slide-left");
});  

//  Menu Add Class Close    
$('.mdl-layout__obfuscator').click(function(){
  $(".mob-menu").removeClass("slide-left");
});  

var domWidth = $(window).width();
function moveElements() {
var mobMenu = $('.mob-menu'),
$mainNav = $('.main-nav'),
respNav = $('.resp-nav'),
mainHdr = $(".global-header");
  
if( domWidth < 700) {
  //alert(domWidth);
  $('.main-nav').appendTo('.resp-nav');
}
} . 

$(window).on('load resize',function() {
  // alert('hi');
  moveElements();   
  $(window).resize(function() {
    moveElements();
  });   

});
```

```css
/* ---------------------------------------------------
GLOBAL HEADER PAGE
----------------------------------------------------- */

textarea,
input,
button {
  outline: none;
}

.txtlabel {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #706e6b;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  display: block;
}

.global-header {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #e8ebf3;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #e8ebf3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #e8ebf3;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.g-logo {
  padding: 7px 24px;
  float: left;
}

.m-g-logo {
  display: none;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  float: left;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  display: none;
}

.resp-nav {
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.mob-menu {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 3px 0 #b5b7bd;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 0 3px 0 #b5b7bd;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0 3px 0 #b5b7bd;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-285px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-285px);
  transform: translateX(-285px);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #333;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 240px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 3px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.profile-info {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.profile-icon {
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  margin: 8px;
  display: block;
}

.profpic {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #394961;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
}

.profile-info span {
  color: #626579;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prof-name {
  float: left;
  width: 68%;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.prof-name a.link {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 3px;
}

.prof-name a.link:first-child {
  position: relative;
}

.prof-name a.link:first-child:after {
  content: "|";
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  color: #9ea6a9;
}

.icon-hamburger {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-nav {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.main-nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: #626579;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  display: block;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  color: #00a0e7;
}

.main-nav li a.active {
  color: #00a0e7;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #00a0e7;
  background-color: #eef0f6;
}

.nav-icon {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.pull-right i[class^='icon-'] {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
}

.icon-search {
  background: url("../../imgs/global-header/icn-search.svg") no-repeat 4px 5px;
}

.icon-notification {
  background: url("../../imgs/global-header/icn-notification.svg") no-repeat 8px 8px;
}

.icon-profile {
  background: #394961 url("../../imgs/global-header/avatar.svg") no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon-profile:after {
  background: url("../../imgs/global-header/page-1.svg") no-repeat;
  display: block;
  width: 9px;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: -20px;
}

.icon-profile:before {
  background: url("../../imgs/global-header/avatar-icon.svg") no-repeat;
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 7px;
  right: 8px;
}

.nav-icon:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-icon:not(.active):hover {
  background-color: #eef0f6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.usage {
  list-style: none;
}

.usage ul {
  list-style: disc;
  list-style-position: outside;
}


/* search */

.srch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

ul,
ol {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ui-front {
  list-style: none!important;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #626579;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 240px!important;
  min-width: 110px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid #F1F5F6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 8px!important;
}

.ui-front li {
  padding: 8px 8px!important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  z-index: 99999;
}

.mdl-layout__obfuscator {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color;
  transition-property: background-color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

.slide-left~.mdl-layout__obfuscator {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  visibility: visible;
}

.slide-menu {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-285px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-285px);
  transform: translateX(-285px);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #333;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 3px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .main-nav {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .main-nav ul {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .main-nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-icon:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
  }
  .g-logo {
    display: none;
  }
  .m-g-logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 24px;
    float: left;
  }
  .hamburger-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .global-header .rightmenu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
  }
  .mob-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .global-header {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>


<div class="global-header">
  <div class="mob-menu">
    <div class="profile-info">
      <div class="profpic"><i class="profile-icon"></i></div>
      <div class="prof-name">
        <span>Marvin Duncan</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link">Profile</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="resp-nav"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-left">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="g-logo" title="Genpact Cora">Logo</a>
  </div>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active">Label 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Label 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="pull-right rightmenu">
    <div class="nav-icon" title="Profile"><i class="icon-profile">&#9786;</i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mob-view">
    <span class="hamburger-menu">
      <button class="icon-hamburger"></button>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="m-g-logo" title="Genpact Cora">Logo</a>
      </span>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-layout__obfuscator"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably because this line only happens once:

```
var domWidth = $(window).width();
```

You need to place that line of code within your moveElements function, so that it continually checks the width of the window.

Additionally, I'd suggest not using 'appendTo' to move something. It is tricky to move pieces of the DOM around like this and you can get in a mess easily. Better to use CSS to move the display of something. Or, if you can't achieve it with CSS alone - maybe have two instances, and show/hide them as needed.

Comment: Thanks @benjaminhull. There are couple of reason i chose jquery to achieve it. 1. Since it is dynamic menu i can't keep copy of menu in the responsive container which can be shown on window resize. 2. I want internet explorer ie9 and above support

Comment: Well then you could use jQuery to COPY the DOM element once (when the page first loads). And then use show/hide during window resizing. I am just suggesting ways to make your life easier.

Comment: @Mustafa.B if my suggestion resolved the issue, I'd appreciate you ticking my answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: I agree CSS is the way to go. and with the right media queries you don't have to use any new CSS for desktop (IE9)

Answer (score 0):

change  $(window).width(); to $(document).width();

i tried and it worked

Comment: They should provide the exact same result.

Comment: Thanks Faizal Hussain. If you see the codepen link and resize the result window the menu doesn't restore to it position when u resize from mobile to desktop view

Comment: did you try using media queries